# How can I use react-error-overlay outside create-react-app?

Tags: create-react-app

I want to use [react-error-overlay](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-error-overlay) package from create-react-app outside the create-react-app.

But it doesn't provide any document about how to apply it.

Does anyone know how to make that happened?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- Install the react-error-overlay package via npm
- Add a require.resolve to your app entry point array

  ```
  app: [
      require.resolve('react-error-overlay'),
      './src/app/'
  ],
  ```
- Add the setup function to your webpack-dev-server configuration so you can add the middleware

  ```
  setup(app) {
      app.use(errorOverlayMiddleware());
  }
  ```

All done

Comment: can you add an example of this working for you? I am getting an error.

Comment: what error did you get? i am getting `Cannot find module 'react-error-overlay/middleware'`

Answer (score 0):

Option B - Roll back your `react-error-overlay` to a 1.x compatible version inside your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

hello just leaving a tip - if you want to just use the runtime overlay, do this: https://twitter.com/swyx/status/961413452446257152

you can also synchronously call the buildtime overlay but that is more involved and is best done using the errorOverlayMiddleware (which FYI has moved to react-dev-utils)

good luck